# P/Invoke Write To Boot Sector

Tags: c#, .net, io, pinvoke

I'm making a (non-production) utility in .NET (C#) for preloading raw data onto an SD Card. I'm trying to avoid using a file system because the embedded processor I'm working with doesn't have enough resources to implement a file system manager. So far, I've read through a bunch of Stack Overflow posts and other resources (such as pinvoke.net), but haven't been able to successfully write data to sector 0 of an SD card. I'm positive I'm missing something very obvious. Anyway here is the relevant code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

public class RawIO
{
    public const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    public const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    public const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    public const short INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

    // P/Invoke functions
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
        string fileName,
        uint fileAccess,
        uint fileShare,
        IntPtr securityAttributes, // optional SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure can be passed
        uint creationDisposition,
        uint flagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr template);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SetFilePointer(IntPtr handle, int lDistanceToMove, out int lpDistanceToMoveHigh, uint dwMoveMethod);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, byte [] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    public static IntPtr RawOpenVolume(string path)
    {
        // Acquire the handle
        IntPtr handle = CreateFile(
            path,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        if (handle.ToInt32() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
        }

        return handle;
    }

    public static int RawWriteVolume(IntPtr handle, byte[] buffer, int count)
    {
        uint bytesWritten;
        bool result = WriteFile(handle, buffer, count, out bytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (!result)
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
        }
        return (int) bytesWritten;
    }
}
```

I call the code as such in `Main()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnop"); 
    IntPtr handle = RawIO.RawOpenVolume("\\\\.\\G:");
    int bytesWritten = RawIO.RawWriteVolume(handle, buffer, buffer.Length);
}
```

However, when I look at a hex dump of the volume, I see no such sequence of bytes. I don't get any errors. Plus, when I use the exact same handle for reading, I'm able to read from the volume (albeit starting at sector 8192, but that is a different problem.) I'm pretty new to .NET and the Windows API, so I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious. I appreciate any advice I can get.

Comment: If you are on Windows Vista or 7, are you running it as an administrator?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 Home x64, and I'm running it as an administrator.

Comment: OK, I was just checking because Windows is really picky about that. Have you tried opening it as \\.\PhysicalDiskX where X is it's disk number? You can find out it's disk number in the disk management interface (diskmgmt.msc)

Comment: Hmmm, I've replaced `"\\\\.\\G"` with `"\\\\.\\PhysicalDisk1"` and I get a file not found exception (HR code `0x80007002`).

Comment: Odd, I guess that won't work. Have you tried this in any other language? Maybe you actually can't get physical disk access from .NET code

Comment: Windows might be buffering the writes.  Have you tried removing the device, forcing Windows to flush the buffer, before examining it?